# absを使用したときに出てくるエラーについて

Tags: python

abs(-100+200)/2と入力した際に、

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-41fe9b40b102> in <module>()
----> 1 abs(-100+200)/2

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

とでてきます。
普通に絶対値を計算したいのですが、できません。
初心者なのでどこか見落としてるかもしれませんが、何度やっても解決できません。

Comment: 何をどのように実行し、入力したのかが不明です。質問に情報を追記すれば回答がつきやすくなると思います。※「abs(-100+200)/2」は問題ないと思います。

Comment: abs という名前の変数を定義してしまっているのでしょう。例えば、`abs = 1` などです。

Answer (score 3):

そのコードの前で、absと言う変数を定義してませんか
定義してるなら、その変数の名前を変えましょう